# Qt GET request strange response

Tags: c++, qt, networking, httprequest, qtnetwork

I'm writing a program to log into a game a get some information from the account.
After making a post request with username and password, I make a get request in the same location in order to download the needed html source. 
However, doing `qDebug()<<QString(reply->readAll());`
prints `"\u001F?\b"` ,instead of the entire source code of the page.

The get reply has status code 200, and the error() function returns NetworkError(NoError). 
For the post and get requests I'm using header information obtained from chrome's network tab in developer options combined with cookies obtained from previous response headers.

I'm doing a get request after the log-in post request because that's what seems to happen in the actual webpage, as displayed in developer options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response might be gzipped.  Does unzipping happen to yield the expected result?

Comment: This is a guess.  I pasted your characters into a file and tried to unzip them command line in unix and failed, but there may be a file header I'm missing.  Never tried to do that that before.

Comment: A comment from this https://forum.qt.io/topic/4089/solved-downloading-gzip-file-but-it-s-no-longer-compressed-when-i-try-to-open-the-local-file/5 " topic states : _"From a quick look at the Qt sources, it seems that QNetworkAccessmanager and friends automatically decodes (uncompresses) gzipped data, if the header "content-encoding" is set to "gzip"."_ But even if the data would be compressed, I should get a much longer reply I guess ?

Comment: After writing the ByteArray to a file and opening it with WinRAR I got the expected output. You were indeed right :)